# How to write collapsable navbar from Bootstrap 3 in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I need a little help. Here's my code i wrote in Bootstrap-3 for collapse-navbar but when i want to write it in Bootstrap-4 it doesn't work. Whatever I tried from the commands failed. Can someone help me and tell me what to do or write.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="menu-categories.html">
            <span class="cutlery"></span><br class="hidden-xs"> Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="info-sign"></span><br class="hidden-xs"> About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="certificate"></span><br class="hidden-xs"> Awards</a>
        </li>
        <li id="phone" class="hidden-xs">
          <a href="tel:111-111-111">
            <span>111-111-111</span></a><div>* We Deliver</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>```


**Here is your Responsive Bootstrap navigation bar**
````